# Inserting a row on a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, insert, row

Here is my code to insert a row at row 3.

```
    function copyCredits(){

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('New Credits'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), 1);
    }
```

The button to run this script is on a different sheet. The code doesn't generate any errors, but doesn't add the row.

Comment: Share more information about the condition when it will be transferred and if you can create a minimum reproducible sheet so we can see how your data works?

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertRowBeforePositionThree() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("New Credits");
  sh.insertRowBefore(3)

}
```